# Is it possible to dynamically set commands for a j2me element?

Tags: java-me, label, midp, lcdui

I have a StringItem which works like a button. The standard menu items(Back on the left side and Next on the right side are always present). The thing I want to do is to leave Back menu item on the left and change Next menu item's label. Is it possible?

I tried to create a new Command with the necessary label and add to the stringiteim but it doesn't replace Next command, it just creates a menu item called Menu with subitems-  Next and My command label.

How can I remove Next or change its label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Command API](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Command.html) does not allow to set new label, so your only option as you correctly guessed was to add the new command. You just forgot one thing...

> ...I tried to create a new Command with the necessary label and add to the stringitem but it doesn't replace Next command, it just creates a menu item called Menu with subitems- Next and My command label...

...when doing above, you forgot to remove "Next" command. Code to replace command should be about as follows:

```
    myForm.removeCommand(nextCommand); // removes "Next" cmd
    myForm.addCommand(myCommand); // adds "My" cmd
```

or, if you use commands associated with Item ([ItemCommandListener API](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/ItemCommandListener.html)) instead of Form,

```
    // myStringItem below is your StringItem above
    myStringItem.removeCommand(nextCommand); // removes "Next" cmd
    myStringItem.addCommand(myCommand); // adds "My" cmd
```